# Why does Task.WhenAll occasionally take a long time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, task-parallel-library

I've got an ASP.NET site that is running a modest amount of requests (about 500rpm split across 3 servers), and usually the requests take about 15ms. However, I've found that there are frequently requests that take much longer (1s or more). I've narrowed the latency down to a call to `Task.WhenAll`. Here's an example of the offending code:

```
var taskA = dbA.GetA(id);
var taskB = dbB.GetB(id);
var taskC = dbC.GetC(id);
var taskD = dbD.GetD(id);

await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC, taskD);
```

Each individual task is measured and takes less than 10ms to complete. I've pinpointed the delay down to the `Task.WhenAll` call, and it seems to have something to do with how the task is scheduled. As far as I can tell, there's not a lot of pressure on the TPL task pool, so I'm at a loss for why the performance is so sporadic.

Comment: I would try using a sniffer and see if time gaps on the internet correlate with the gaps in application.

Comment: I've pinpointed it down to the call to TPL. The individual network requests are measured and never exceed 10ms. It's happening in process.

Comment: @EricAndres Sorry this is off topic but for my own curiosity: What tool did you use to come to such a conclusion?

Comment: We're doing measurements with Stopwatch.StartNew, and then sending them to an Influx database.

Comment: Did you measure `Task.WhenAll` or `await Task.WhenAll`? Because you would be measuring very different things

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Overall I'd recommend profiling with JetBrains dotTrace using timeline mode, and you should be able to pinpoint the issue very quickly. It could be a gen 2 GC collection, or a task occasionally taking longer than you expect. dotTrace has a 10 days free trial, so it's plenty enough for this kind of investigation

Comment: That's an option I've considered, but it's hard to reproduce the problem in a dev environment.

Comment: You can profile in production, there is a remote agent you can directly copy on the server without installation. It can be attached to a live process without restarting it. Expect a 10-15% CPU hit during profiling.

Comment: I'm wondering what would happen if you raise the priority of the application?  I'm suspecting another process that has higher priority is running which is creating the sporadic performance.  The Timer Tick scheduling is causing the issue.  How about turning off the virus checker?  Is your application read/writing to a file?  Creating logs?

Comment: Honestly, I'd suspect the GC first, this is the most likely culprit. You should try to correlate the value of the "# Gen 2 Collections" performance counter with the moment the pauses happen

Comment: I've been suspecting a memory issue. The site is running on AWS t2.mediums, which have 4GB of memory, and having been riding at 70-80% of capacity. We ran perfmon overnight, so we'll see if there are any revelations in there

Answer (score 0):

Async operation involve context switches, which are time consuming. Unfortunately, not always in a deterministic way. To speed things up in your case, try to prefix your Task.WhenAll call with ConfigureAwait(false), as follows:

```
await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC, taskD).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will eliminate an additional context switch, which is actually recommended approach for server-side applications.

Comment: Forgetting about the fact that `ConfigureAwait` won't change anything about context switches, we're talking of a full **second** of delay, not a few microseconds

Comment: Here is an experiment I'd do:
1. Before calling the Task.WhenAll, start another task too (which hwill just print something in the output) and then call the Task.WhenAll. Would be interesting to see whether the new task has the same delay or it'll finish again very fast, and the issue is indeed in the Task.WhenAll related

Answer (score -2):

Creating threads takes overhead.  Depending on what you're doing, you can also try a Parallel.ForEach.

```
public static void yourMethod(int id){

    var tasks = new List<IMyCustomType> { new dbA.GetA(id), new dbB.GetB(id), new dbC.GetC(id), new dbD.GetD(id)};

    // Your simple stopwatch for timing
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    // For each 'tasks' list item, call 'executeTasks' (Max 10 occurrences)
    // - Processing for all tasks will be complete before 
    //   continuing processing on the main thread
    Parallel.ForEach(tasks, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, executeTasks);

    stopWatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Completed execution in:  " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}

private static void executeTasks(string obj)
{
    // Your task's work here. 
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the OP is using multiple threads?  All you know is that they have asynchronous operations, and that they're doing DB calls (which needs no threads, so if the OP is using them there's no reason to do so).  *Your* code is adding a bunch of threading work.  Unnecessary threading work at that.  The code also doesn't come anywhere close to compiling, give that the OP's methods all return tasks, and aren't synchronous the way you're treating them.